# Tracing tool missing in QGIS 3.28.4

Tags: qgis, editing, snapping, tracing

I miss the tracing tool in the snapping properties window. [The documentation of QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#automatic-tracing) states that it should be found here. Is there an existing workaround?

To the person who edited my post: I know about a workaround, but would rather love to know, if this is a bug to be reportet to the QGIS developers or if I need to change some properties in my QGIS.

Here is the toolbar:
[image]

Comment: If the answer of eurojam doesn't solve your problem, it would help, if you provide a screenshot of your QGIS toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

it is still there (QGIS 3.28.4, Windows 11)

[image]

Comment: Got it! I have to open the snapping tools as toolbar instead of trying to find it via the project snapping properties. Thanks! I didn't know that this exists.

Comment: Does anyone know why the duality of this toolbar and the project snapping properties exist?